# Can't access <Select> on keyboard with screen reader

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, accessibility, screen-readers

I have  html element (actually React styled component) that is used for changing interval on stock price chart.

```
          <Select
            aria-label="select interval"
            name="interval"
            id="line-chart-interval"
            defaultValue={chartInterval}
            onChange={({ target }) => {
              setChartInterval(target.value);
            }}
            on
          >
            <option value="1min">1 min</option>
            <option value="5min">5 min</option>
            <option value="15min">15 min</option>
            <option value="30min">30 min</option>
            <option value="1h">1 h</option>
            <option value="2h">2 h</option>
            <option value="4h">4 h</option>
            <option value="1day">1 day</option>
            <option value="1week">1 week</option>
            <option value="1month">1 month</option>
          </Select>
```

I can normaly access the options when I click ENTER but when screen reader is on It is somehow blocked.

Screen reader extension that I use: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-reader/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn?hl=en

Comment: Your `Select` is a component not a dom element, so where do `Select` comes from?

Comment: Your screenreader seems to be old, and itself even advises to install something else.

Comment: @dbuchet select is just a styled component so It has custom styles and beside that should act like an select html element

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I didn't notice that, my bad. Do you now any good screen readers that I can use for checking accessibility?

Comment: I would not rely on screen reader plugins.  Use a real screen reader.  [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/download/) is free and is a [widely used screen reader](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey9/#browsercombos).

Comment: Use a true screen reader really in use, instead of a random browser extension that nobody  use for real. It's even better if you can test with several screen readers on several platforms: NVDA or Jaws on windows, VoiceOver on MacOS and iOS, and Talkback on Android.